# Materialize CSS columns wrapping unexpectedly

Tags: materialize

I am experiencing an issue with Materialize CSS columns. Essentially I would expect the following to render as follows.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8
```

However, the result looks like this.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
        7 8

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4 m3 l2">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="responsive-img circle hoverable">
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m3 l2">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="responsive-img circle hoverable">
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m3 l2">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="responsive-img circle hoverable">
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m3 l2">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="responsive-img circle hoverable">
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m3 l2">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="responsive-img circle hoverable">
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m3 l2">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="responsive-img circle hoverable">
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m3 l2">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="responsive-img circle hoverable">
  </div>
  <div class="col s4 m3 l2">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="responsive-img circle hoverable">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have since discovered that if I isolate the html (as above) into a new file, the issue is not occurring.

It is going to be a bit tricky to give an example of the full picture, as the HTML is being rendered with Django, however would anyone be able to point me in the right direction as to what could possibly be causing this.

Edit: If it means anything, it is in a modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks fine, this is your initial code with icons: https://codepen.io/flyingDonut/pen/qBZrMgm

Update as requested by the OP: Adding a custom couple of flex classes (container and item) and giving them a wrap solves the img issue: https://codepen.io/flyingDonut/pen/RwaVwjP

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Edit Profile</title>

    <!-- Materialize -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <style>
        .cc {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: flex-start !important;
            flex-wrap: wrap !important;
        }

        .cr {
            padding: 4px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1980px) {
            .cr {
                flex-basis: 10%;
            }
        }
            @media screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
            .cr {
                flex-basis: 14.2%;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
            .cr {
                flex-basis: 20%;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
            .cr {
                flex-basis: 33.3%;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .cr {
                flex-basis: 50%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#test" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger">Change Image</a>
        <div id="test" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="center">Change Profile Avatar</h4>
                <div class="cc">
                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic1"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic2"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic3"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic4"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic5"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic6"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic7"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic8"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic9"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic10"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic11"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic12"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic13"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div class="cr">
                        <img
                            id="profilePic14"
                            src="https://i.imgur.com/MM0HXX0.png"
                            class="small circle hoverable responsive-img"
                            style="cursor: pointer"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".modal").modal();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I have rendered the section to a string, and included it in a code pen. https://codepen.io/brendan-stubbs/pen/ZEWedmq

After trying to replace my images, so that they could be accessed in the codepen, I norticed the issue seemed to sort itself out, so I am pretty sure it is the images (I uploaded them to S3, so they are available in the codepen) I hoever have no idea what could be wrong with them.

Comment: Hi, you can add a couple of new classes and make them `flex` and give them width according to number of images you have, like so https://codepen.io/flyingDonut/pen/RwaVwjP

Comment: Thanks, this is getting a bit closer to solving it. However the amount of images is going to be dynamic, and it needs to be repsonsive (I have done some media queries already),  so I can't guarentee that all of the rows are going to be "full" all of the time. Is there rule I can apply that will slot them in from the left (in this case) and not mess up the alignment?

Comment: I am still trying to understand what is going wrong with the Materialize columns though. What I am trying to do should work out the box.

Comment: You're right! I've been on this for close to 4 hours because I simply didn't get why introducing a simple `img` module in a `col` would make it misbehave while icons or text do nothing. A couple of old SO answers mentioned erasing a line `body.width` in the JS. This line is no longer in the code so that's a bummer.

Comment: I'll suggest to take it up with the creators on https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues
because the right-to-left alignment issue is something no one has encountered to date. I hope you get it to work, I'd love to stay updated if you find a solution :)

Comment: I forgot to highlight that I updated the codepen: https://codepen.io/flyingDonut/pen/RwaVwjP with some media queries and a custom flexbox just in case :) Good luck

Comment: What is really strange is it seems to work properly if I change the images.
Thanks so much for your help. If I manage to figure it out, I will let you know what the problem was

Comment: I just implemented your solution and it solves the problem. Thanks very much.

If you edit your answer to show the CSS and the classes applied I will mark it as the answer. I am going to remove those images from S3, so you might want to use a sample instead.

Comment: I'm glad it turned out helpful! Well, here you go. Edited the answer AND the codepen. I took a random icon from google and replaced the S3 link. Cheers!

Comment: Just wanted to confirm if the custom icon I added works for you in the sample code edited later?